# Elixir - generate list of strings for navigational (breadcrumb purposes)

Tags: elixir

I'm pretty new to Elixir (loving it so far) and have been trying to figure out how to take a simple String such as

```
"folder1/folder2/folder3/last_folder"
```

and turn it into a list of navigation links for each part of the path (except for the last_folder):

`["https://wherever/folder1", "https://wherever/folder2",  "https://wherever/folder3"]`

There must be a pretty simple way to do this - perhaps with recursion?

Comment: Did you mean `/folder1` and `/folder1/folder2` and `/folder1/folder2/folder3`? That is, something like breadcrumbs?

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for explicit recursion. Just split the path by `/` and do an `Enum.scan/3`, concatenating the accumulator and the current part with `"/"` as separator:

```
path = "folder1/folder2/folder3/last_folder"
parts = String.split(path, "/")

Enum.scan(parts, "", fn part, acc ->
  acc <> "/" <> part
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
["/folder1", "/folder1/folder2", "/folder1/folder2/folder3",
 "/folder1/folder2/folder3/last_folder"]
```

If you don't want the last one, you can drop the last part from `parts` by doing this instead:

```
parts = String.split(path, "/") |> Enum.drop(-1)
```

```
["/folder1", "/folder1/folder2", "/folder1/folder2/folder3"]
```

If you modify the initial value of the accumulator, you can add the base URL if you want:

```
path = "folder1/folder2/folder3/last_folder"
parts = String.split(path, "/") |> Enum.drop(-1)
Enum.scan(parts, "https://wherever", fn part, acc ->
  acc <> "/" <> part
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

```
["https://wherever/folder1", "https://wherever/folder1/folder2",
 "https://wherever/folder1/folder2/folder3"]
```

Comment: That would fail horribly if the folder names aren't unique.

Comment: Sorry, our comments were crossing and I had just deleted mine - thanks for your solution - it's the best one.